# Epimorphism from arbitrary module to a free module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $F$ be a free module and let $f:M \rightarrow F$ be an epimorphism from a module $M$ onto $F$. Show that there exists a homomorphism $h:F \rightarrow M$ such that $f \circ h = id_F$ and deduce from it that if $N < M$ and $M/N$ is free then $N$ has a complement in $M$, i.e. there exists a submodule $C$ of $M$ such that $M = N \oplus C$.

What I have done: first of all, there exists a homomorphism $\theta : F \rightarrow M$ such that $\theta (x_i) = y_i$, where $x_i \in X$, and $X$ is a basis in $F$, and $\{y_i\}$ is a set of generators in B. After this, extend $\theta$ by linearity, and so we have constructed a homomorphism from $F$ to $M$.
Will this homomorphism be that we are looking for? And how to deduce the second part using this knowledge?

Comment: You should also use the given homomorphism $f:F\to M$ somewhere..

Comment: It seems that $\theta(F) = M$, and $f(M) = F$ (because $f$ is an epimorphism), however I am not sure that I'm thinking in a right direction.

Answer (score 1):

This probably will not be an epimorphism you're looking for, since you haven't used the map $f$ at all.

Just look at the property $f \circ h = id$. If $x_i \in X$ are basis elements of $F$, and $f$ is epimorphism, there are some $y_i \in M$ such that $f(y_i) = x_i$. Now, $x_i = id(x_i) = f(y_i)$, so it does not leave us many options besides setting $h(x_i) = y_i$. Since $F$ is free, $h$ is well defined. Prove that this map makes everything work.

Comment: Thank you, extension by linearity helps to show that such an $h$ is that we are looking for, but I am still stuck with complement.

Comment: The complement will obviously be kernel of $f$.